# Can't disable USB on QT Py CircuitPython

Tags: adafruit-circuitpython

CircuitPython 8.2.8
Adafruit QT Py M0 with samd21e18

I am saying this to my boot.py file:

```
import storage
storage.disable_usb_drive()
```

But everything it restart the file is empty. And the USB drive CIRCUITPY shows up.